# Find a Substring in a Range on Another Sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have sheet A with a list of domains in the A column e.g:

```
exampledomain.com

someexampledomain.com
```

On sheet B in the A column I have the same domains but specific pages e.g:

```
https://exampledomain.com/page-of-stuff/

https://anotherexampledomain.com/more-pages-of-stuff/

https://otherexampledomain.com/lots-of-pages-of-stuff/
```

I want to find out whether exampledomain.com appears in the a column of sheet B as a substring. I found another post using regex but from what i understand it only works with one cell to one cell as I've messed around with it for a while.

These are ones i tried:

```
=if(search(A2,'All Floors'!A:A)>0,1,0)

=IF(REGEXMATCH(A8, 'All Floors'!A:A), 1, 0)
```

Is there anyway to do this? Also would Google Sheets be able to hand this on a large scale?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gZa37vWyxO--vf7ZLAvwGP-Cr2hD2svWPtGsWi6KPVo/edit#gid=1719805041

Comment: @player0 have added it to the question, its the link domain sheet and the formulas are in L and M columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT('Nutriment Links'!A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A))))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer, I've inserted it in the sheet but doesn't seem to work, you're welcome to edit the sheet to test.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uK21be7dhEWGRxRtiNeOXXoLTu59AFhahq_TrNE1tgA/edit#gid=1719805041

Comment: works perfectly, seemed to be a delay in my sheet, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find if the `Domain sheet` url is in the `Nutrition Links` list, you can use following array formula:

```
={COUNT(SEARCH(A2;'Nutriment Links'!A:A))}
```

Work in MS Excel only:(

Comment: Sorry, I looked earlier to fix the #VALUE error, now put in a working formula